# Using pysimplegui, sg.InputText not returning an int but a string for range

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How do I get it to use `low_end` and `high_end` in the range as integers

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue17')

#import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('DarkBlue17')

form = sg.FlexForm('Lucky RandomNumbers', default_element_size=(40, 1))

column1 = [[sg.Text('Column 1', background_color='#d3dfda', justification='center', size=(10,1))],
           [sg.Spin(values=('Spin Box 1', '2', '3'), initial_value='Spin Box 1')],
           [sg.Spin(values=('Spin Box 1', '2', '3'), initial_value='Spin Box 2')],
           [sg.Spin(values=('Spin Box 1', '2', '3'), initial_value='Spin Box 3')]]
layout = [
            [sg.Text('Lucky Number Generator', size=(30, 1), font=("Helvetica", 25))],
    [sg.Text('Enter low value'), sg.InputText('',size=(5, 3),key='low_end'), sg.Text('Enter high value'), sg.InputText('',size=(5, 3), key='high_end')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
    ]
event, values = form.Layout(layout).Read()
randomlist = random.sample(range('low_end'), ('high_end'), 5)

sg.Popup(randomlist, ' ')
```

When I run it I get:

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I have tried several solutions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You already known that a string returned for `sg.InputText` element, so you need to convert it into an integer by user code.

Comment: Jason,that's my problem. I have tried to convert to int but everything fails. It seems like a simple problem that is driving me nuts. in this case the low_end is a 1,and the high_end is 35. I;d just like to see this run in a gui, running in a terminal I can specify input as a int, how do you do it in a gui

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
randomlist = random.sample(range(int(values['low_end']), int(values['high_end'])), 5)
```

You can only get the value if you get it from the values dictionary.